# Sortable JQuery element is offset from cursor after first drag, only if i'm scrolled down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I copy pasted the JQuery example here: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I've done "some" progress. Googling this question gave answers from here but the solutions do not work entirely. I force position: relative for the sortable ID and the ui-state-default and added cursorAt value in the sortable call.

Now if I'm scrolled on a page reload, the first element is aligned with the cursor, but afterwards the same problem occurs. I really don't know what to do anymore. Tips?

This is using a wordpress theme so i'm using !important to stop any other CSS from interrupting.

[image]

```
      <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/resources/demos/style.css'>
      <!-- <style>
      #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
      #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
      #sortable li span { position: relative; margin-left: -1.3em; }
      </style> -->
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js'></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $('#sortable').sortable({cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 }});
        $( '#sortable' ).disableSelection();
        $( '#datepicker').datepicker();
      } );
      </script>



    <div class='formStyle'>
    <form method='post'>
    <div class='cycleText'><p>Choose a starting date</p></div>
    <div class='cycleDate'><input type='date' name='dateCycleStart' id='datepicker'></div><br>
    <div class='cycleText'><p>Drag and drog to order your moon centers.</p></div>
    <div class='sortableStyle'>
    <ul id='sortable'>
      <li name='1' class='ui-state-default'>Hairline<input type='hidden' name='1' value='Hairline'></li>
      <li name='2'class='ui-state-default'>Eyebrows<input type='hidden' name='2' value='Eyebrows'></li>
      <li name='3' class='ui-state-default'>Pinks of Cheeks<input type='hidden' name='3' value='Pinks of Cheeks'></li>
      <li name='4' class='ui-state-default'>Lips<input type='hidden' name='4' value='Lips'></li>
      <li name='5'class='ui-state-default'>Earlobes<input type='hidden' name='5' value='Earlobes'></li>
      <li name='6' class='ui-state-default'>Nape of Neck<input type='hidden' name='6' value='Nape of Neck'></li>
      <li name='7' class='ui-state-default'>Nipples<input type='hidden' name='7' value='Nipples'></li>
      <li name='8'class='ui-state-default'>Navel<input type='hidden' name='8' value='Navel'></li>
      <li name='9' class='ui-state-default'>Inner Thighs<input type='hidden' name='9' value='Inner Thighs'></li>    
      <li name='10' class='ui-state-default'>Clitoris<input type='hidden' name='10' value='Clitoris'></li>
      <li name='11'class='ui-state-default'>Membranes of Vagina<input type='hidden' name='11' value='Membranes of Vagina'></li>  
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='cycleButton'><button type='submit'>Generate Calendar</button></div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#sortable {
    width: 250px;
    position: relative !important;
}

li.ui-state-default.ui-sortable-handle {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: it says cursorAt is not a function. else everything looks great

Comment: How are you seeing that? I see no errors in console and it's the source code straight from the Jquery site so i'm confused

Comment: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tueTT.png)

Comment: Hmm I don't see that error in my console, I'll see what function I can sub it for

Comment: open console in this page and run the snippet

Comment: there is no method called cursorAt in jQuery ui. check the documentation of cursor its an attribute https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cursorAt

Comment: You're right that must of been an attempt I made from months ago. I just don't understand why copy pasting from the website does not give the same result and behavior. I just tried taking from source again just to be sure and I get the same issue

Comment: which wordpress theme you are using? there might be some conflict because of theme css

Comment: It's called "The Core", a paid theme my client is using. I'm looking at the CSS with the console and trying to figure that out but not sure what i should be looking at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized this was only happening on chrome, so when looking up offset issues with browser specifics, I finally got a parameter that worked. Overflow: auto on the UL or container

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
      $('#sortable').sortable({
          containment: "parent",
          tolerance: "pointer"
      });
      $('#sortable').disableSelection();
      $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Still does the same thing